# How to show Collections using LayoutView?

Tags: javascript, marionette

I'm learning Backbone.Marionette and I need to understand how can I show Models in the template using LayoutView.

Based on this example:

App.js:

```
//VIEWS
ArticleView = Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.extend({
    template: "#articleTemplate",
    tagName: 'li',
});

SelectedView = Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.extend({
    template: "#selectedTemplate",
    tagName: 'li',
});

var AppLayoutView = Backbone.Marionette.LayoutView.extend({
  template: "#layout-view-template",

  regions: {
    articles: "#articles",
    selecteds: "#selecteds"
  }
});


myApp.addInitializer(function(options) {
    var layoutView = new AppLayoutView();
    layoutView.render();

    layoutView.articles.show(new ArticleView(options.articles));
    layoutView.selecteds.show(new SelectedView(options.selecteds));
});

nsApp.start({
  articles: Articlescollection,
  selecteds: SelectedsCollection
});
```

index.html:

Layout template and ItemViews templates:

```
<script id="layout-view-template" type="text/template">
  <section>
    <article id="articles">
       /* show My first collection here */ 
    </article>
    <article id="selecteds">
      /* show My second collection here */ 
    </article>
  </section>
</script>

<script type="text/template" id="articleTemplate">
    <img src="<%= thumbnail %>" alt="<%= title %>"  class="img-thumbnail"/>
    <%= title %>
    <hr>
</script>

<script type="text/template" id="selectedTemplate">
    <img src="<%= thumbnail %>" alt="<%= title %>"  class="img-thumbnail"/>
    <%= title %>
    <hr>
</script>
```

I'm really confused here!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pa4ggrbj/26/) which you wish to achieve.

```
nsApp = new Backbone.Marionette.Application();
nsApp.addRegions({ content: '#main' });

Ar  = Backbone.Model.extend({});
Se = Backbone.Model.extend({});

Articlescollection = new Ar({ thumbnail: "test", title: "Test title"});
SelectedsCollection = new Se({ thumbnail: "test", title: "Test title"});

//VIEWS
ArticleView = Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.extend({
    template: "#articleTemplate",
    tagName: 'li',
});

SelectedView = Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.extend({
    template: "#selectedTemplate",
    tagName: 'li',
});

var AppLayoutView = Backbone.Marionette.LayoutView.extend({
  template: "#layout-view-template",
    el: nsApp.content.el,
  regions: {
    articles: "#articles",
    selecteds: "#selected"
  }
});

nsApp.addInitializer(function(options) {
    var layoutView = new AppLayoutView();
    layoutView.render();
    layoutView.articles.show(new ArticleView({model: options.articles}));
    layoutView.selecteds.show(new SelectedView({model: options.selecteds}));
});

nsApp.start({
  articles: Articlescollection,
  selecteds: SelectedsCollection
});
```

And html:

```
<div id="main">
</div>    

<script id="layout-view-template" type="text/template">
  <section> 
    <article id="articles">
       /* show My first collection here */ 
    </article>
    <article id="selected">
      /* show My second collection here */ 
    </article>
  </section>
</script>

<script type="text/template" id="articleTemplate">
        <img src="<%= thumbnail %>" alt="<%= title %>"  class="img-thumbnail"/>

    <%= title %>
    <hr>
</script>

<script type="text/template" id="selectedTemplate">
        <img src="<%= thumbnail %>" alt="<%= title %>"  class="img-thumbnail"/>

    <%= title %>
    <hr>
</script>
```

Instead of collections models were used.

A few things to note:

1. When passing collection or model to Marionette.ItemView pass it as object `{model: yourModelm collection: yourCollection}` like in example. This way Marionette will automatically serialize it and will pass to template. If both model and collection passed model will be serialized.
2. Try to use Marionette.CollectionView/CompositeView for collections and Marionette.ItemView for models when possible.

Missing part from your source code is main region which attaches LayoutView to app's region view.

From fiddle:

```
nsApp = new Backbone.Marionette.Application();
nsApp.addRegions({ content: '#main' });
```

If you wish to use collection instead of model just pass it through instead of model and use cycle to render it.

Hope this will help.

Comment: Thank you Vahan this is very helpful. Now I'm working with ItemView & CollectionView and LayoutView. The motivation behind LayoutView is to handle some buttons' events that exist outside the collectionViews region. Therefor I'm thinking that CompositeView maybe better for this use.

Comment: `CompositeView` is definitely what you want, not all this custom code. `CompositeView`s are basically `LayoutView`s merged with `CollectionView`s.

Comment: @HeinHaraldsonBerg You always welcomed to add you answer without all this custom code.